# 'No active transaction' and 'Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA' when persisting object in filter?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jta

I want to log all requests to my web server using a filter.

At first I tried the normal way I used in my EJBs and web service classes. My program fails as soon as I attempt to persist. I AM able to query (not shown here):

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ConsoleManagement")
protected EntityManager em;
...
private void someMethod(){
        Request userRequest = new Request();
        userRequest.setApikey(apikey);
        userRequest.setFormat(requestedFormat);
        userRequest.setMethod(method);
        userRequest.setRequestIp(ip);
        userRequest.setRequestUrl(requestUrl);
        em.persist(userRequest); // fails here
        em.flush();
}
```

Error:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No active transaction for PuId=WebApi#WebApi.war#PersistenceUnitName
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.getEMInvocationInfo(JPATxEntityManager.java:250)
```

From this I gathered (although could not find any documentation) that filters are not container managed.

I then tried the two following:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ConsoleManagement")
protected EntityManager em;
...
private void someMethod(){
        Request userRequest = new Request();
        userRequest.setApikey(apikey);
        userRequest.setFormat(requestedFormat);
        userRequest.setMethod(method);
        userRequest.setRequestIp(ip);
        userRequest.setRequestUrl(requestUrl);
        em.getTransaction().begin(); // fails here
        em.persist(userRequest);
        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit()
}


@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "ConsoleManagement")
EntityManagerFactory emf;

public void someMethod() {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin(); // fails here
    em.persist(userRequest);
    em.flush();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}
```

Error in both cases:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA.
```

[EDIT] In the case that I inject an EntityManagerFactory via @PersistenceUnit and remove the em.getTransaction().begin(), I get a different error.

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "ConsoleManagement")
EntityManagerFactory emf;

public void someMethod() {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    //em.getTransaction().begin(); 
    em.persist(userRequest);
    em.flush(); // fails here now
    //em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}
```

Error:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No externally managed transaction is currently active for this thread
```

I'm a little stuck now.

[EDIT]
Persistence unit:

```
<persistence-unit name="ConsoleManagement">
    <description>This unit manages user data including user information, user projects, and project api keys</description>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/db2dbcpdb/develop</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.utoronto.websphere.jaxrs.entities.Project</class>
    <class>com.utoronto.websphere.jaxrs.entities.User</class>
    <class>com.utoronto.websphere.jaxrs.entities.Api</class>
    <class>com.utoronto.websphere.jaxrs.entities.Apikey</class>
    <class>com.utoronto.websphere.jaxrs.entities.Version</class>
    <class>com.utoronto.websphere.jaxrs.entities.Request</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Is ConsoleManagement a persistence unit with `transaction-type="JTA"`?

Comment: <jta-data-source>jdbc/db2dbcpdb/develop</jta-data-source> is set. Does that make it automatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec states that if the `transaction-type` is not specified, the default is JTA in a Java EE environment. Since you are using a container managed EntityManager, you cannot begin/commit/rollback the [EntityTransaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html) as if you were in a Java SE environment.

You can access the [UserTransaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html) via the @Resource annotation:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    private void doSomething() {
        // ...
        utx.begin();
        em.persist(foo);
        utx.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Why isn't the container managing the transaction in this case?

Comment: @user2316667 That would happen in an EJB container, but you are accessing the transaction from a servlet filter. I recommend you to create a stateless EJB that persists the `userRequest`, and inject it on your servlet filter.

Comment: So b/c I've set my transaction-type as JTA, I cannot use EntityTranscations, but also because Filters are not container managed, I cannot inject container managed entitymanagers either. So there was no winning. Is that right? [edit] Thanks a lot for the great suggestion. Much cleaner.

Comment: @user2316667 I would need to read the spec to see if it is possible to let the web container manage the transaction, but it does not look natural to me. With an EJB layer, you can choose between BMT or CMT with the `@TransactionManagement` annotation, and also avoid concurrency problems - Container managed EntityManagers injected into servlet instances variables are not thread-safe.